# Symfony2 / Doctrine: Reading "deleted" data when using Gedmo's doctrine extensions

Tags: symfony, doctrine, soft-delete

I'm building a Symfony2 project and am using `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` ([GitHub](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions)) to implement soft delete. My question is whether there's a way to "disable" or "override" softdelete, or even detect if something has been soft deleted.

Here's the situation:

I have a "note" entity that references a "user" entity. A specific note references a user that has been soft deleted. Even though the user has been deleted, it returns true for TWIG's "is defined" logic and can even return the id of the deleted user. However, if I query for any other information (including the "deletedAt" parameter that marks whether or not it is been deleted) I get a 500 "Entity was not found" error.

Since the data is actually still there, and since the note itself hasn't been deleted, I'd still like to say who's written the note, even though the user has been deleted.

Is that possible? If not, how do I properly detect whether something has been soft deleted? Like I said, `$note->getUser()` still retrieves an object and returns true for any null / "is defined" comparisons.

Comment: This is a known limitation of Doctrine2, see https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4543

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the relationship loading to `eager`, this will prevent lazy loading of objects with just an `id` and nothing else.

You can find more information on eager loading and it's annotation here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html.

As for my code, this is how it looks like when defining a link to a `User` now:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="answers", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

In this case, the `User` entity can have multiple `answers`. When loading a `User` from the `answer` perspective, this will work:

```
foreach($answers as $answer) {
    $user = $answer->getUser();

    if (!$user) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by :

```
$filter = $em->getFilters()->enable('soft-deleteable');
$filter->disableForEntity('Entity\User');
$filter->enableForEntity('Entity\Note');
```

Comment: It can be **'softdeleteable'** instead of 'soft-deleteable' ... (i'm using stof doctrine extensions)

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily disable soft-delete so that deleted items are returned in your results.  [See the documentation](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md), specifically interesting for you is the section that reads:

> This will disable the SoftDeleteable filter, so entities which were
>   "soft-deleted" will appear in results
>   $em->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');

So, first run the code above on your Entity Manager `$em` and then use it to collect your `$note`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want parent entities (i.e. notes) that have been soft deleted. Disabling the filter will also return deleted notes which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I made a helper function for this so the only thing I have to write is this:

```
$softDeleted = GedmoSoftDeletableUtils::getSoftDeletedFor(
    MyClass:class, // the class for the soft-deleted items
    $em, // Pass an EntityManager
    // Optionally pass some extra Criteria if you want:
    [Criteria::expr()->eq('someExtraField', 'someValue')]
);
```

This is the general helper function, just put it somewhere as a Utility class

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class GedmoSoftDeletableUtils
{    
    public static function getSoftDeletedFor(
        string $class,
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        ?array $extraExpressions = []
    ): ArrayCollection {
        // First disable the soft-deleted filter for this entity
        $em->getFilters()->getFilter('softdeleteable')->disableForEntity($class);

        // The base criteria for getting the soft-deleted elements
        $criteria = (new Criteria())->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->neq('deletedAt', null));

        foreach ($extraExpressions as $expression) {
            $criteria->andWhere($expression);
        }

        // Trigger the LazyCriteriaCollection with toArray() before enabling the "softDeletableFilter" again
        $result = new ArrayCollection(
            $em->getRepository($class)->matching($criteria)->toArray()
        );

        // Enable the soft-deleted filter again for this entity
        $em->getFilters()->getFilter('softdeleteable')->enableForEntity($class);

        return $result;
    }
}
```